# Minus the lower row from top row all the way down in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subtraction

I have a query which is stated below which show the total km run of my vehicle. Now I want to make a subtraction. I want this like if I have a sample below:

```
date          totkm
2015-27-01    81199
2015-27-01    81198
2015-27-01    81197
```

Now, what I want as a result is something like this:

```
date         totkm
2015-27-01    0
2015-27-01    1
2015-27-01    1
```

As you can see I subtracted the first row and second row then subtracted the second row and the third row and so on and so forth.

Really would like to ask for some help.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(char(10), TRXDATE, 126) DESC) AS Row,
    (CONVERT(char(10), TRXDATE, 126)) AS NEWDATE, 
    kmrun AS totkm 
FROM [SMSGPS].[dbo].tblCUrrent_ROI 
WHERE 
    TRXDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-26 06:00:00' AND '2015-01-26 08:30:00'
    AND PLATENO = 'NILO-MOTORCYCLE' 
ORDER BY CONVERT(char(10), TRXDATE, 126) DESC
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: 2012 Sir is what I'm using. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you convert the date to an ISO datetime string for sorting? That doesn't seem to make sense. Why is kmrun varchar (as you state in a comment to wewesthemenace's answer) instead of being a numeric data type?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LAG` function.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    [Date]  DATE,
    TotKM   VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
('20150127', '81199'),
('20150127', '81198'),
('20150127', '81197');

SELECT
    [Date],
    TotKM = LAG(CAST(TotKM AS INT), 1, CAST(TotKM AS INT)) OVER(ORDER BY [Date], CAST(TotKM AS INT) DESC) - TotKM
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: I did something like this `SELECT
    TRXDATE,
    kmrun = LAG(kmrun, 1, kmrun) OVER(ORDER BY TRXDATE) - kmrun
FROM [SMSGPS].[dbo].tblCUrrent_ROI`   it returns an error like **Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator.
**

Comment: What's the datatype of `kmrun`?

Comment: varchar(50) Sir. Thanks again.

Comment: I think you want to `ORDER BY [Date], TotKM DESC` for the `LAG()` function. Otherwise the rows could be returned in any order since all the dates are equal.

Comment: You should cast `kmrun` to int first.

Comment: can i ask how?...sorry for the question

Comment: It doesn't return the value given. It got mixed up.

Comment: `SELECT
    (CONVERT(char(10), TRXDATE, 126)) AS NEWDATE,kmrun,
    kmrun = LAG(ROUND(CAST(kmrun AS INT),0), 1, ROUND(CAST(kmrun AS INT),0)) OVER(ORDER BY TRXDATE, ROUND(CAST(kmrun AS INT),0) DESC) - kmrun
FROM [SMSGPS].[dbo].tblCUrrent_ROI
where TRXDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-26 06:00:00' AND '2015-01-26 08:30:00' AND PLATENO = 'NILO-MOTORCYCLE' ORDER BY CONVERT(char(10), TRXDATE, 126) DESC
` but this code mixed all things up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have default order of records in your table, I am not applying ORDER BY on Date column. Instead I use SELECT 0 to get the order for ROW_NUMBER.

I am writing query in SQL Server 2008, that supports in SQL Server 2012 too.

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #tblCUrrent_ROI([DATE] DATE,TOTKM VARCHAR(50)) 

INSERT INTO #tblCUrrent_ROI
SELECT '2015-01-27',81199
UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-01-27',81198
UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-01-27',81197
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Row number in default order
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0))RNO,*
    FROM #tblCUrrent_ROI
)
SELECT C1.RNO,C1.[DATE],ISNULL(CAST(C2.TOTKM AS INT)-CAST(C1.TOTKM AS INT),0) KM
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO+1
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91525/1) to view result